# String tokenizer- strange behavior with verified array

Tags: c, unix, malloc, segmentation-fault, text-processing

**EDIT** to incorporate suggestions to code and update question

I have to implement a word wrap feature in the program, and have chosen a greedy algorithm of

```
//I use fread to take in the file in one bite, the parse the resulting array.  The 
//four lines below are from another function.
char *readBuffer= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * fileSize);    
int size= ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);
size_t result= fread(readBuffer, 1, size, fp);

int spaceLeft= termWidth;
int outputLines=0, tempLength, printCount-0;
char *temp, *newLine="\n";

temp= strtok(readBuffer, " "),
fputs(temp, stdout); //prints out a 11, when should be a 1, then exits

while ((outputLines < termHeight) && (temp != NULL)){
    strcat(temp, " ");
    tempLength= strlen(temp);

    if (spaceLeft > tempLength){
      fputs(temp, stdout);
      spaceLeft -= tempLength+1;
    } else {
      strcat(newLine, temp);
      spaceLeft= termWidth-(tempLength);
      outputLines++;
      newLines="\n";
    }
    temp= strtok(NULL, " ");
    printCount+= tempLength //debugger display
  }
}
```

With this code, I verified that the file was read in correctly to readBuffer by a 
  `fputs(readBuffer, stdout)` command.  However, the first fputs writes a 11 to the screen, when it should be a 1.  Then it skips the while loop and exits.

OutputLines is set to 0, and termHeight is the result of a `termHeight=termios.ws_row-1` call.

If temp is printing a value to the screen, and (outputLines= 0) > termHeight, how can temp be null in this instance?

Comment: `strtok` will return `null` if there are no more tokens in the string, maybe that's what's happening?

Comment: Thats what I thought, but the file size is 1.6KB, and has roughly 90 lines of text in it.  Why would it return null?  if I output the text via `fputs` without `strtok`, all the text displays.

Comment: Does the file have any NUL characters ('\0') in it?  That would interfere with `strtok()`.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem may be that `fgets` retrieves only a single line from the file.  [The man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) describes this.  The code appears to expect that it reads the entire file.  Thus, temp would be NULL after that first line is processed (single token if no spaces in it).

Not knowing the length of the text you are reading nor the values of `termHeight` or `termWidth`, it's not possible to know the execution path.  But the segfault is probably occurring on the `strlen()` call on the NULL `temp` value after that line is processed.  While this is not a complete fix, the `while` statement should probably use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
while ((outputLines > termHeight) && (temp != NULL){
```

And depending on how you want to process it, you may need another `fgets` call to read the next line after `strtok` returns NULL.  Or, alternatively, use [`fread`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) to retrieve the entire file in one call.